# Instance variable value not being printed

Tags: java

I am trying to learn java. currently learning about types of variables.
i have written a small program defining instance,local,static variables and trying to print the same from with in the main method. but i am getting error saying "non static variable i cannot be referenced from static context. Below is my program

```
public class variable{
  int i=5;
  static int j=10;
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int k=15;
    System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println(j);
    System.out.println(k);
  }
}
```

Please let me know whats wrong with the program

Comment: Please format your code with correct indentation. Not for this question, but in your IDE. Having good formatting helps you to see problems far easier.

Comment: as i am a beginner i am using notepad to write the code instead of any tool.

Comment: You can not call non-static variables in static methods as "i" is a non-static variable & used in static main method

Comment: @user1861033 - You've asked 29 questions before this. You should know that your code should be properly formatted (by now) :)

Comment: @user1861033 i strongly recommend you to use an IDE such as eclipse. It might seem complex at first, but it gives you a lot of help while developing.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a instance of variable and access i

```
variable v = new variable();

// then access v.i
```

BTW use Camelcase for you class name.

Answer (score 0):

Options:

Make a new instance of your class so you can reach i. In fact it is maybe not the best option, because you should make it private, and add a getter method... :)

OR

You could change `int i` to `static int i`, because of the static main method.

+1 : it is better to have classnames camescased... :)

Comment: The whole point of that project is to have a variable that is not static.

Comment: @f1sh Yes, sorry, you are right...

Answer (score 0):

int i should be static becasue static context cant refer to the non-static variable